# Mapping string to map of unsigned int to unsigned int

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, stream

I am attempting to map every word from cin to the line number that word occurs on to the line it occurs on and the number of times it occurs on the line.

I'm not sure if my loop will work. I think I have an understanding on maps but I'm not 100% sure if this will work and I cant print it to test because I haven't figured out how I should print it. My question is, does my map look okay?

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  map<string, map<unsigned int, unsigned int> > table;

  unsigned int linenum = 1;
  string line;

  while ( getline(cin, line) != cin.eof()){
    istringstream iss(line);
    string word;
    while(iss  >> word){
      ++table[word][linenum];
    }
    linenum++;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      while ( getline(cin, line) != cin.eof() ){
                                /*~~~~~~~~~~~~ Don't use this, 
                                               the comparison is incorrect */
```

To print it simply loop over your map of maps:

```
for(const auto& x:table)
{ 
    std::cout << x.first << ' ';
    for(const auto& y:x.second)
    {
     std::cout << y.first << ":" << y.second << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

See [*`here`*](http://rextester.com/UPIMEB83361)

For C++98 use:

```
    for(mIt x = table.begin();
        x != table.end();
        ++x )
{ 
    std::cout << x->first << ' ' ;
    for( It y = x->second.begin();
        y != x->second.end();
        ++y )
    {
     std::cout << y->first << ":" << y->second << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i can only use c98 @P0W

Comment: @etorr96 their return types are different, please see appropriate references